# Unable to install glibc-langpack-no on centos7

Tags: php, locale, centos7

I got a requirement from my developer team saying that the staging server is missing Norwegian language pack.

when i check locale i see the below 3 entries but the developer says, the utf8 is missing for this language

```
locale -a
...
no_NO
no_NO.ISO-8859-1
norwegian
...
```

Then i try to install this language package as show below

```
[root@staging ~]# yum install glibc-langpack-no
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nforce.com
 * epel: cdn.centos.no
 * extras: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
 * remi-php71: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-php72: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-php74: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * updates: nl.mirrors.clouvider.net
rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server/x86_64/signature      |  833 B     00:00     
rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server/x86_64/signature      | 1.8 kB     00:00 !!! 
rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server-source/signature      |  836 B     00:00     
rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server-source/signature      | 1.0 kB     00:00 !!! 
varnishcache_varnish66/x86_64/signature        |  833 B     00:00     
varnishcache_varnish66/x86_64/signature        | 1.8 kB     00:00 !!! 
varnishcache_varnish66-source/signature        |  833 B     00:00     
varnishcache_varnish66-source/signature        |  951 B     00:00 !!! 
No package glibc-langpack-no available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

```
[root@staging ~]# localedef -i no_NO -f UTF-8 no_NO.UTF-8
cannot open locale definition file `no_NO': No such file or directory
```

It seems that there are no language pack we can install on centos7 but from centos8, if this is the case, how the existing all other language packs have been installed on this server?

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS Linux 7 the glibc-common package has the following locales suffixed with NO:

- `nb_NO` "Norwegian Bokmål"
- `nn_NO` "Norwegian Nynorsk"
- `se_NO` "Northern Sami"

In CentOS Stream 8 and 9, and in Fedora also, they are separate packages, but the same three are available:

- glibc-langpack-nb (`nb_NO`)
- glibc-langpack-nn (`nn_NO`)
- glibc-langpack-se (`se_NO`)

All three of these locales have corresponding files in the [Unicode CLDR Project](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/release-44-1/common/main).  I don't see any files for `no_NO`, so I'm not sure that is a proper locale.